# a variable sequence of for in python

Tags: python

I'm starting to program in python and I came across a problem that I don't know how to solve.

I have a nested `for`s function, where the number of nested `for`s depends on an input parameter, for example, if I have the input parameter set to 2, I have to have:

```
for loop1 in range (0, limit):
   for loop2 in range (0, limit):
      print ('loop1: {} loop2: {}'.format(loop1,loop2))
```

If it is set equal to 3, I must have:

```
for loop1 in range (0, limit):
   for loop2 in range (0, limit):
      for loop3 in range (0, limit):
         print ('loop1: {} loop2: {} loop3 {}'.format(loop1,loop2, loop3))
```

The results will be:

for 2:

```
0,0
0,1
1,0
1,1
```

for 3:

```
0,0,0
0,0,1
0,1,0
1,0,0
...
2,2,2
```

And so on.

Does anyone out there have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Without knowing more about your use case, the fact that you need this functionality is likely indicative of a flaw in your base design. Can you elaborate on what *exactly* your use case is for this, so that the community might be able to suggest alternative approaches to your design?

Comment: Are you trying to do anything more than the print statement within your loops? If not then there is most certainly a better way to do so than dynamically nesting for-loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
import itertools

for i in itertools.product(list(range(x)), repeat=x):
    print(','.join(i), end=' ')
```

`itertools.product` returns all products of range from 0 to x - 1, then you join and print them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with the `repeat` argument to generate these sequences.

```
from itertools import product

def gen_sequence(limit):
    for vals in product(range(limit), repeat=limit):
        print(','.join(str(i) for i in vals))
```

Example

```
>>> gen_sequence(2)
0,0
0,1
1,0
1,1

>>> gen_sequence(3)
0,0,0
0,0,1
0,0,2
...
2,2,0
2,2,1
2,2,2
```

Answer (score 2):

This is known as a cartesian product and is available in Python via [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```py
import itertools

for i in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=3):
    print(i)
```

To specify many you can just enter multiple iterators.

```py
for i in itertools.product(range(1), range(2), range(3)):
    print(i)
```

Comment: olá to complete, is there some way to specify the range of each separately, for example, the first for will vary 0-3, and the second 0-2 and make all products between this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something that has to be solved with a recursive function. something like:

```
def loops(n,limit):
    for loop in range (0, limit):
        n-=1
        row = [loop]
        if n == 1:
            ...
        else:    
            row = row + loops(n,limit)
```

I didn't have time to finetune, but you get the idea.  If not, do some research on recursive functions.